# My sql filter by recent date

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

**TABLE_1** :

```
id | equipment        |
1  | voltimeter       |
2  | amperemeter      |
3  | wattimeter       |
4  | eletrical gloves |
```

**TABLE_2**

```
id  |  id_table1  |  inspection_date
1   |  2          | 2017-01-05
1   |  2          | 2017-02-07
1   |  3          | 2017-05-09
1   |  3          | 2018-09-23
1   |  2          | 2018-05-09
1   |  2          | 2017-11-05
```

I wanna list ALL values on TABLE_1 with a column with the recentest inspection date of TABLE_2

Result Should be:

```
id | equipment        |  last_inspection_date
1  | voltimeter       | 
2  | amperemeter      | 2018-05-09
3  | wattimeter       | 2018-09-23
4  | eletrical gloves |
```

What I have is this:

```
SELECT t1.*, Max(t2.inspection_date) LastInspectionDate
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.id_table1 = t1.id
```

What I'm doing wrong here? I only get 1 row :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join ond subquery group by id_table1 for max date

```
select a.equipment 
from table_1 a
left  join ( 

  select id_table1, max(inspection_date)
  from table_2 
  group by id_table1 ) t on a.id = t.id_table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two queries: one for table_1 and one subquery for the related latest inspection date from table_2.

```
select
  id,
  equipment,
  (select max(inspection_date) from table_2 t2 where t2.id_table1 = t1.id) as last_insp
from table_1 t1
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.equipment, MAX(t2.inspection_date) AS LastInspectionDate
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.id_table1 = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

(`MAX` is an aggregation function. It aggregates all data to one row, if you don't specify per what columns you want the maximum. In your case per table_1 row, i.e. per `t1.id`.)